# can we use .jpg format images for mobile applications I.e iphone and android

Tags: iphone

i am working on mobile application where i need to display a background image using css sprites. here is the problem image size is 1600px width and 480px height. when i convert this image to png the file size is 400kb. and in jpg format it is 80kb.
  So, my question is whether can i use the jpg format image in mobile application. especially in iphone and android........?

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 0):

Yes

We can use jpg files BUT it is preferred to use png files as they are very lightweight to use.So as far as mobile apps are concerned png are the ones used.

Cheers

Comment: Depending on the image, PNG files can be considerably larger than JPEG.